# Zipping a file with password in Java

Tags: java, compression, password-protection

I'm trying to compress a file into a protected zip file, but I search for how to make and I found no answer, is there anyway to zip a unique file into a password protect .zip??

To zip my file I'm using this code

```
  public class ZipFile {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            String sourceFile = "test1.txt";
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("compressed.zip");
            ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
            File fileToZip = new File(sourceFile);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileToZip);
            ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileToZip.getName());
            zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
            final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
            }
            zipOut.close();
            fis.close();
            fos.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you asking if there is a way to zip a file and then when a person attempts to open it, it asks for a username/password before it decides to unzip it??

Comment: No, just to compress a file with password... Just as common compressing using setPassword

Comment: @WendlerZacariotto You can't do this with the standard API. You will need a 3rd party library such as [winzipaes](https://code.google.com/archive/p/winzipaes/).

Comment: It worked, thanks :D